# Problem in reusing same serversocket

Tags: java, sockets

I have implement the following code to create a SSL server socket.

```
    public void createConnection(){
     port =8888;
    listen = true;
            isSvrRuning = true;
            try {


                String KEYSTORE = Config.KEYSTORE_FILE;
                // String KEYSTORE = "/u04/app/ato/data/keystore/ATradSvrKeyStore";
                char[] KEYSTOREPW = "abcd".toCharArray();
                char[] KEYPW = "abcd".toCharArray();
                com.sun.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory tmf;

                boolean requireClientAuthentication;

                java.security.Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
                java.security.KeyStore keystore = java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(
                        "JKS");
                keystore.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE), KEYSTOREPW);

                com.sun.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory kmf = com.sun.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
                kmf.init(keystore, KEYPW);

                com.sun.net.ssl.SSLContext sslc = com.sun.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("SSLv3");
                tmf = com.sun.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("sunx509");
                tmf.init(keystore);

                sslc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
                SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = sslc.getServerSocketFactory();

                ssocket = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket();
                try {
                    ssocket.setReuseAddress(true);
                } catch (SocketException ex) {
                    loggerSvr.log(Level.SEVERE, "SocketException in setting timeout for serverSocket.");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                ssocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
                ssocket.setNeedClientAuth(true);
                while (listen) {
                    //wait for client to connect//
                    socket = ssocket.accept();
        // here goes the code which need to handle a new connection
    }

}catch(){
//there are several catch blocks to catch all checked exceptions
}
}
```

If there is a problem or exception in the above socket I close the socket and recreate another server socket by calling above method. But the problem is some time I cannot recreate the server socket using the same port. It gives following error when I am trying to do it.

```
Server socket allocation error for the specific port
```

I have also set the reusable property when creating the socket.can some one tell what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I could figure out the problem. But the problem was some where else. Above code does not have any arror. Initial Implementer of the code did not expose the real error. That's why I could not figure out. Pardon me about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Server socket allocation error for the specific port

That's not a Java exception message. That comes from some undisclosed point in your code. Judging by the accuracy of the error message you are printing if setReuseAddress() fails, it may have nothing whatsoever to do with the actual error condition. As you *are* calling setReuseAddress(true) I find it rather unlikely that it's a bind problem. You would have to tell us the *actual* exception and error message.

There's a moral here: don't make up your own error messages; use the one provided in the exception.

Also this code is ten years out of date. All the com.sun.net.ssl.* stuff should be replaced by javax.net.ssl.* And you don't need to add the provider. @since JDK 1.3.

Comment: Thank you for your comment EJP.As you told problem was not in this code. Person initially implement the above code has not exposed the real exception. So I also could not figure out where is the actual arror initially. Actual problem was some where else. Next time I will make sure to indicate the actual  error.Also I noticed that most of the method used in the above code is deprecated. Can you tell me what kind of risk that I'm having with the above code. Thank you about the comments again